# Jekyll - Plugins don't work when sorting posts

Tags: ruby, markdown, jekyll

I have a plugin called [jekyll-spaceship](https://github.com/jeffreytse/jekyll-spaceship#configuration) in Jekyll - It helps me to use video feature (not available in Markdown): `! [Video] (https://example.com/video?height=500)`

Everything works perfectly on post page.

But in home page, I am listing posts like this:

```
<div id="main" class="site-main">                                                          
  <div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">
      {% for post in paginator.posts %}
      <header class="entry-header">
        <h1 class="entry-title">
          <a href="{{post.url}}" rel="bookmark">{{post.title}}</a>
        </h1>
      </header>
      <div class="entry-content">{{ post.content }}</div>
      {% endfor %}
    </div></div>
</div>
```

And, this event turns it into an image. So I can't use the plugin feature. I think `{% for post in paginator.posts %}` turns it into normal Markdown.

How can I fix this problem?

By the way, I am using [jekyll-paginate-v2](https://github.com/sverrirs/jekyll-paginate-v2) for paginating but doesn't matter, its the same like normal Jekyll

Comment: Do you really want to show the content of each post within your loop. Does make it  sense in a toc?

Comment: I think this issue has been addressed and fixed, you can refer to [spaceship with paginate-v2](https://github.com/jeffreytse/jekyll-spaceship/issues/62), and please try again with the latest version.